# The page isn’t redirecting properly- Error_too_maney_redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

[Image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbYD8.jpg)

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

```
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Many time i have deleted the cookies but still facing the same issue after redirecting http to https kindly give me permanent solution...